# CMake set variable readonly, protect from override

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to protect variable from override in CMake? Or make variable const/readonly.

```
set(VAR content READONLY)
set(VAR overridden)  ## Warning "variable VAR is readonly"
```

I'd like to receive warning, and VAR should still equal to "content".

Answer (score 4):

CMake has no internal mechanisms for make the variable readonly. Moreover, even automatic CMake variables like `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` could be modified.

But CMake provides mechanism for **watch** the variable - [variable_watch](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/variable_watch.html). Using this mechanism one could *emulate* readonly property of the variable.

Code below provides `set_readonly` macro for declare readonly variables:

```
# Analogue for 'set' command which defines readonly variable.
#
# Usage:
# set_readonly(FOO value)
macro(set_readonly VAR)
  # Set the variable itself
  set("${VAR}" "${ARGN}")
  # Store the variable's value for restore it upon modifications.
  set("_${VAR}_readonly_val" "${ARGN}")
  # Register a watcher for a variable
  variable_watch("${VAR}" readonly_guard)
endmacro()

# Watcher for a variable which emulates readonly property.
macro(readonly_guard VAR access value current_list_file stack)
  if ("${access}" STREQUAL "MODIFIED_ACCESS")
    message(WARNING "Attempt to change readonly variable '${VAR}'!")
    # Restore a value of the variable to the initial one.
    set(${VAR} "${_${VAR}_readonly_val}")
  endif()
endmacro()
```

Usage example:

```
# Define readonly variable 'FOO'
set_readonly(FOO "123" "456")

message(STATUS "FOO initial value: ${FOO}")
# Attempt to change the variable's value.
# This will trigger a warning.
set(FOO "456")

message(STATUS "FOO new value: ${FOO}")
```

This example would produce following output:

```
-- FOO initial value: 123;456
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:6 (message):
  Attempt to change readonly variable 'FOO'!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9999 (readonly_guard)
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (set)


-- FOO new value: 123;456
```

(While `CMakeLists.txt:26` is an actual line with `set(FOO ...)` command, `CMakeLists.txt:9999` is some "magic" line).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use [CACHE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry) keyword to command SET.

> Sets the given cache  (cache entry). Since cache entries are meant to provide user-settable values **this does not overwrite existing cache entries** by default.

```
SET(VAR value CACHE)
```